# Visual Studio 2017 Plugin: Reference to type 'TeamFoundationServer' could not be found

Tags: c#, tfs, visual-studio-2017, tfs-2015

I work on a Visual Studio Plugin that I want to update from vs2015 to vs2017. After updating all the nuget packages I got the error:

CS7069 Reference to type 'TeamFoundationServer' claims it is defined in 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client', but it could not be found

The Code causing this ist:

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection =/*..*/;
DocumentService doc = Dte.GetObject("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.DocumentService") as DocumentService;

IWorkItemDocument wiDoc = doc.GetWorkItem(teamProjectCollection, id, this);
```

So I don't use 'TeamFoundationServer' as it self because I use the other overload of the GetWorkItem method.

Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient is on Version 15.112.1, so it should contain correct Version.

I try to compile in vs2015 and 2017 getting in both cases the same error.

Comment: Not sure on this but, does the Dte.GetObject call an actual object?  Does the "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.DocumentService" actually exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The location of assembly `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.dll` in VS 2017 should be in `%Program Files%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer`, while in VS 2015, it locates at `%Programfiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer`, you need to re-load it.

Comment: I used this assemblies instead of the nuget packages and now it works. Thank you